# Как добавить домен в MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, windows, сервер

Здравствуйте!
Ситуация такая. База данных и Студия установлены на сервере в одном домене, а компьютеры, с которых требуется подключаться к БД, - в другом домене. Требуется подключаться к БД посредством Windows - аутентификации. Можно ли как-нибудь добавить сторонний домен в Студию?

Comment: Здравствуйте.
AD вам в помощь. Никаких проблем с аутентификацией, которая вам нужна.

Answer (score 2):

Вам нужно настроить доверительные отошения между доменами - [Cross Domain Trust](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc757352(v=ws.10).aspx). Тогда между ними будет работать аутентификация, и пользователи из другого домена будут полноценно "видны".

Настраивется достаточно просто, стандартным визардом на Domain Controller.

Comment: А настройка вот этого Cross Domain Trust должна осуществляться на контроллере домена БД или другом домене?

Comment: @No_Com на контроллере домена БД, если будете настраивать one-way trust. если решите делать two-way - то вроде бы без разницы.

Comment: Ясно! Спасибо, я попробую. Если заработает, то дам вам знать.

Answer (score 0):

Кросс-доменная аутентификация работает, если знать особенности NTLM - токен вычисляется на основе логина и пароля, без учёта домена. Предположим, что есть два домена:

- `TEST_DOMAIN`
- `MAIN_DOMAIN`

И есть пользователь SQL Server с Windows-аутентификацией:
 - `TEST_DOMAIN\UserLogin` с паролем `UserPassword`;

Если на любой машине с любом домене создать локального пользователя
`UserLogin` с паролем `UserPassword`, то он сможет выполнить Windows-аутентификацию на SQL Server.

Если в домене `MAIN_DOMAIN` создать пользователя `MAIN_DOMAIN\UserLogin` с паролем `UserPassword`, то он сможет выполнить Windows-аутентификацию на SQL Server.

Единственное условие - полное совпадение логинов и паролей. В таком случае NTLM-токен будет одинаковым (он формируется на основе логина и пароля, без учёта домена) для двух пользователей с разных доменов и windows-аутентификация сработает.

Comment: Это не подходит, т.к. я не знаю логины и пароли пользователей, которые будут подключаться к БД.